# Java prints output twice in a very specific circumstance

Tags: java, console, printing

```
System.out.print("My string: ");
```

My string: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

```
System.out.print("My string  ");
```

My string  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

```
System.out.print("My string:  ");
```

My string:  My string:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Printing a string that ends with **a colon and two spaces** will make it print twice. What is happening here?

---

Edit: looks like it's a bug in Netbeans indeed

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that behavior on Netbeans, when running JUnit tests. It that also your case? Seems to be just a bug.

Comment: <eclipse-fanboy>Ah, one more reason not to use Netbeans.</eclipse-fanboy> ;)

Comment: BalusC: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog. (gaah!!)

Answer (score 2):

I think the output stream's buffering is making you interpret what you see wrongly. Try using `println()`.

Comment: Or add a call to flush after the call to print.

Comment: IIRC, `System.out` autoflushes like crazy.

Comment: Looks like println() only prints it once.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin. It only autoflushes complete lines.

Answer (score 0):

Which java version do you have? It doesn't happen in 1.6.0_16

Are you sure it's not some danging lines in the unix shell (if you're on unix)?. Try with `System.out.println("My string:  ");`

Comment: See my edit, it seems to be a confirmed bug and the fix will be there in a future patch.